# data is undefined after fetch post request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

user.lists has a value before going into fetch request but is undefined after fetch post request. Associations are set up on the backend and the information is being persisted to the database. Only after the post request is it undefined

```
let username = document.getElementById("username").value
let email = document.getElementById("email").value
let lists = document.getElementById("todo").value

    let user = {
    username: username,
    email: email,
    lists: lists
    }

    console.log(user.lists)
    fetch(`${BASE_URL}/users`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(user)
    })
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(user => {
        console.log(user.lists)
        //let u = new User(user.id, user.username, user.email, user.lists)
        //u.renderUser()

    })
```

Comment: The variable `user` passed as a param name has a different scope than the one from the variable assigned to an object. `user` is assigned to the argument passed to the function. What does `console.log(JSON.stringify(user))` show?

Comment: it returns the id, username, and email {"id":86,"username":"test","email":"test","created_at":"2020-08-08T01:57:58.061Z","updated_at":"2020-08-08T01:57:58.061Z"}

Comment: the second `user`'s value has changed.

Answer (score 0):

You've two `user` variable here with two different scopes.

```
let user = {
    username: username,
    email: email,
    lists: lists
}
```

`user` is declared and initialized first in the code snippet above, but then you override this variable in your final `then` call with

```
.then(user => {
    console.log(user.lists)
    //let u = new User(user.id, user.username, user.email, user.lists)
    //u.renderUser()

})
```

When you `console.log(user.lists)`, I think you expect to see the value of `list` property on the first `user` declaration. If this is not the case then you don't have list property on the `user` variable present in the `thenable`. I suggest you change the name of one of the two `user` variables.

Comment: When I change the variable name on the 2nd user in the thenable to userObj I still get undefined in the console.log(userObj.lists). Any thoughts on why console.log(userObj.username) returns its data but not userObj.lists? When I check the database the userObj.lists exists but not when its called after the fetch post

Comment: do you send `list` property in the response from `.../users` post request? From the looks of it, it seems like you don't get `list` property in the response.

Comment: user and list have a has many relationship. In `../users` there is not a list property listed

Comment: Sorry, I meant `lists` not `list` in the above comments. If you're not sending `lists` property in the response from your web server, then `userObj.lists` will of course show `undefined`. Could you just show the response of `console.log(userObj);`

Comment: Code snippet of `/users`: `[{"id":72,"username":"Natalie","email":"123@abc.com","created_at":"2020-08-08T01:22:41.631Z","updated_at":"2020-08-08T01:22:41.631Z"}, ... ]` and of `/lists`: `{"id":1,"description":"item 0","user_id":72,"created_at":"2020-08-08T01:22:41.694Z","updated_at":"2020-08-08T01:22:41.694Z"}, ...]`

Comment: If that's the response you get when you hit `${BASE_URL}/users` and `${BASE_URL}/lists`, respectively, then you can clearly see that you don't have any `lists` property in the response which you get from `/users`.

Comment: `{id: 97, username: "hi", email: "hi", created_at: "2020-08-08T02:52:30.152Z", updated_at: "2020-08-08T02:52:30.152Z"}created_at: "2020-08-08T02:52:30.152Z"email: "hi"id: 97updated_at: "2020-08-08T02:52:30.152Z"username: "hi" `